# Copied script not working on different google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below script working fine on my "Order sheet" (project name is "Order sheet code" file is "Code.gs")

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var col = activeCell.getColumn();
  var row = activeCell.getRow();

  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetName() == 'Order Sheet') {

    if (col == 6) { // assuming status is in column 6 (E), adapt if needed
      if (col == 6 && sheet.getRange(row, col + 1).isBlank())
        sheet.getRange(row, col + 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('DDD, dd MMM'); // change the display format to your preference here  
    }
    if (col == 6 && sheet.getRange(row, col).isBlank())
      sheet.getRange(row, col + 1).setValue("")
  }
}
```

Now I have a new sheet, "Work Hours" where I want to utilize the same sort of functionality (different column and time instead of date), but even when I copy this script to a new script file (Project "Work Hours code", file name "Code.gs") and change the SheetName (line 7) to 'Work Hours' it doesn't seem to work.

I thought maybe it was because I had 2 projects with the Code.gs file, but changing that to Code2.gs didn't make a difference (changed it back, just in case).

Also, eventually I want this to run even when the sheet is closed, because I need it to record when data comes in from an external source. Is that possible? I presume I'd have the change the variable for "sheet" since it wouldn't be active?

Comment: Please add all relevant tags when asking a question, it hurts visibility If you omit them. Always try to include product tag like [tag:google-sheets], language ([tag:google-apps-script]) and API-specific ([tag:google-sheets-api]) where applicable. Also please avoid chit-chat and “thank you” comments in questions. Finally, avoid using “not working” in title or in body, there is always a specific issue that you should correctly describe instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will work on both sheets:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh= e.range.getSheet()
  var shts=['Order Sheet','Work Hours']
  if (shts.indexOf(sh.getName()!=-1)) {
  //do whatever you want in here
   
  }
}
```

or if want to do different things on each sheet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh= e.range.getSheet()
  if(sh.getName() == 'Order Sheet') {
  }
  if(sh.getName() == 'Work Order') {
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean I should rather stick with 1 Code file for multiple sheets?

Comment: It's easier to integrate them if you do it all in one code.  Another way of looking at it is that it's easier to get some unwanted interaction if you do it in two codes.

Comment: I have amended my code to the below:

`function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet      = e.range.getSheet();
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var col        = activeCell.getColumn();
  var row        = activeCell.getRow();
 
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == 'Order Sheet') {
  if (col == 6) {  // assuming status is in column 6 (F), adapt if needed
      if (col == 6 && sheet.getRange(row, col+1).isBlank())
      sheet.getRange(row, col+1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('DDD, dd MMM'); // change the display format to your preference here  
     }  `

No luck for Work Hours...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for other newbies like me with this issue:
BE EXTRA VIGILANT... I know this is obvious, but especially with copy/paste: it seems I had an extra { in my original script...
Probably happened when copy-pasting and deleting a few times when I was trying different things.

I also found why I couldn't make @Cooper 's suggestion work: I was working on BOUND SCRIPTS (ie scripts bound to a specific sheet)